# Change Firestore QuerySnaphot Size in realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to conditionally change the `querySnapshot.size` to 0 in runtime so that the `forEach()` runs only specified number of time ? And would doing it be a good practice ?

```js
db.collection("cities").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    let count = 0;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if(count === 5) {
            //change querySnapshot.size
        }
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: "Is there any way to change the querySnapshot.size in realtime?" => What do you exactly mean? the querySnapshot represents the result of a query. Do you want to change the query parameters, e.g. filtering?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I want to change the length of `querySnapshot` to 0 so that `forEach()` ends.

Comment: So you just want to treat 5 `DocumentSnapshot` returned by the query and then stop the loop.

Comment: Yeah, exactly that's why I need.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment "you want to treat 5 `DocumentSnapshot`s returned by the query and then stop the (`forEach()`) loop."

I would advise to then query for only 5 documents instead of querying for ALL the documents in the collection and stop "treating" them (i.e. exiting the loop) when you have treated 5 of them.

For that you should use the [`limit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#limit) method, as follows:

```
db.collection("cities")
.limit(5)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {...});
```

In addition to potentially saving some download time you will save some read cost.

Comment: Yeah, I know we could do it like this but I want to select particular docs from all of them as per some condition.

Comment: Can't you build a query with those conditions? It is really not a good idea to do the filtering in the front-end.

Comment: No pre-built function is there for the query which I want to do.

Comment: I'm applying queries on doc that are under querySnapshot

Comment: There is no pre-built way to stop the forEach. You could throw an Exception. But again, this is not a recommended approach. If you are able to apply a given filtering in the front-end, based on the field values of the documents, you shoudl be able to apply it in a query (you maybe need to adapt the fields, but it shoudl be possible)

Comment: I only want to store those docs which contains the keyword user searched for and that too limited to some particular number.

Comment: Could I achieve that using where clause or I've to use some third party libraries ?

Comment: You should share your code and search criteria. Without that it’s difficult to answer.

Comment: I understand that but that would completely change the meaning of this question.